# Force NPM to use package-lock.json with "vue-cli-service build" command?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I'm currently the using command `vue-cli-service build` to build my Vue project. `vue-cli-service` itself runs NPM.

How can I force it to use `package-lock.json` (use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`)?